# Is relying on short-circuit evaluation good design?

Tags: evaluation, short-circuiting

Are there alternatives that would be more preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short-circuit evaluation is a crucial feature of most modern programming languages and there's no reason to avoid relying on it. Without it pointer-related tests would be (unnecessarily) much more complicated and *less readable*.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's good design, everyone knows to expect it and it beats using nested conditionals.